# sending constant data to phone-call activity

Tags: java, android-intent

I am working on an android app that intiates a phone call, and then goes to some other intent activity.
Now what I want is that how can this new activity send a text or audio to the phone_call activity, and this audio be heard on the receiver end of the call.

I have to deliver this tomorrow and am completely stuck. In need of help. THanks